# Error: no suitable drivers for jdbc in android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, azure, jdbc

I am aware that there is a number of people having issues on here about this. I have read through a number of them but haven't any of their solutions to help me.

I have included the library in my app build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
...
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
     compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.7.0@aar'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
     compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar')
 }
```

I have a classpath in the project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.0.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}
```

I have the lib in the library folder:

[image: [My lib folder]]

and I have implimented getting the drivers in my program:

```
String hostName = "whereyaatserver.database.windows.net";
String dbName = "whereyaatdatabase";
String user = "Capstone_Admin";
String password = "Swde4321!";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://whereyaatserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=whereyaatdatabase;user=Capstone_Admin@whereyaatserver;password=Swde4321!;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        Connection connection = null;

public Mapping() throws SQLException {
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapping);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I have added a CLASSPATH variable to the environment variable point into my lib folder:

[image: [my CLASSPATH variable]]

I am not entirely sure where I am going wrong. I clearly am in some why but I am not sure if I am making a small mistake or going about this entirely the wrong way. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the best answer is "don't use JDBC in an Android app". Your `CLASSPATH` is pointless, as that is Windows, and you are writing an app that runs on Android. And your `url` appears to be for SQL Server, while your driver appears to be for MySQL.

Comment: what would be the best way to have a database for android using Azure if not using sql?

Comment: I cannot speak in terms of Azure. Outside of that, usually, we use some form of Web service on the server that talks to the database, with the mobile app talking to the Web service.

Comment: Okay, sadly I have to use Azure for external reasons. But your comments may help me figure out what I should be doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it thanks to the aid of a comment by CommonsWare. The issue was that I had imported the mysql library rather than the sql library.

Here are the new dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.7.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' //  compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre7/sqljdbc41.jar')
}
```

And the new lib folder:

[image: [New Lib folder]]

Just putting this here in case someone else is as silly as I